# Split rows of pandas textual dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text

I have a pandas textual dataframe which looks like this:

```
+-----------------------------------+
|               text                |
+-----------------------------------+
| A very long sentence              |
+-----------------------------------+
| Another very long sentence        |
+-----------------------------------+
```

But I would like to split each row with pieces of sentences no more than 512 words in every row:

```
+-----------------------------------+
|               text                |
+-----------------------------------+
| A piece of very long sentence     |
+-----------------------------------+
| One more piece of long sentence   |
+-----------------------------------+
```

I can convert my data into python list but `str.split()` works with separators.

It there a pythonic way to do this?

Comment: so suppose the first sentence consists of 2048 words, then you to split it to 4 consecutive rows?is that it?

Comment: In what sense you are considering words?..ie..like for this sentence `A piece of very long sentence`  Is it 29 words or 6 words?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split) to split text into "words" by whitespace, then use [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) to chunk the list of words into groups of `512`. Then use [`DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to split into multiple rows:

```
limit = 512  # Set to limit words per row
df['text'] = (
    df['text'].str.split().apply(lambda s: [
        ' '.join(s[pos:pos + limit])  # group into 512 size chunks
        for pos in range(0, len(s), limit)
    ])
)
# Explode Into Multiple Rows
df = df.explode('text')
```

*Note this approach joins back with `' '` meaning that if there is formatting information saved like `\n` or `\t` this will be lost.

---

Sample program using [`lorem`](https://pypi.org/project/lorem/) to generate sample data:

```
import random

import pandas as pd
from lorem.text import TextLorem

random.seed(5)  # For reproducibility
gen = TextLorem(srange=(512, 1023))

df = pd.DataFrame({'text': [gen.sentence() for _ in range(2)]})

limit = 512
df['text'] = (
    df['text'].str.split().apply(lambda s: [
        ' '.join(s[pos:pos + limit])  # group into 512 size chunks
        for pos in range(0, len(s), limit)
    ])
)
# Explode Into Multiple Rows
df = df.explode('text')

# Sanity Check to count words per row
df['word_count'] = df['text'].str.split().str.len()
print(df)
```

`df`:

```
                                                text  word_count
0  Tempora labore velit sit voluptatem tempora qu...         512
0  quiquia quaerat sit sit quisquam quisquam non ...         261
1  Ut labore ipsum aliquam sit adipisci sed neque...         512
1  quisquam velit sit ipsum tempora amet aliquam ...         352
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try via `str.split()`+`str.join()` if the sentence are seperated by `' '` :

```
df['text']=df['text'].str.split().str[:512].str.join(' ')
```

Now For checking the length(after running the above code) you can do:

```
df['text_len']=df['text'].str.split().str.len()
```

Comment: My dataset has 10931 rows and after running your code it has also 10931 rows. Column 'text_len' has such values as 53, 219, 76, 114 and other. I am not sure why it works this way ):

Comment: @alyferryhalo It woudn't affect the length or shape of your dataframe it will make the length of sentence inside the text column to 512 or less depending upon the no of words each sentence has....In other words the sentence inside the text don't exceeds more than 512 words